# How long should you wait after submitting a revise and resubmit before you should contact the journal?

Tags: peer-review

It's been six weeks since I have sent paper for a second review after I received revise&resubmit decision from the first round. Is this a typical time period or should I send a query to the journal?

Currently the paper is under the status "with editor" for a couple of days after it has been "under review". The journal is in the field of telecommunications.

Comment: I've had a major revision turned around in 3 weeks, and a minor revision turned around in 3 months. Anything is possible.

Answer (score 2):

The time for the second go-around is often the same as for the first go-around. So, if the journal allows reviewers 3 months for a review, you have to expect this much (at least) also for the review of the revision.

Comment: Shouldn't it be much shorter because reviewers are already familiar with the paper?

Comment: Maybe. But that doesn't mean that they will move it up on their priority list.

Comment: I know it is a field-specific question, but as a general rule, how long it takes after the status is Decision in process?

Comment: It means that the reviewers have written their reports and the editor needs to make a decision. For me this typically takes 2-3 days, but others handle things in batch. I would think that if an editor takes 2-3 weeks, then that is fair.

Comment: I suppose that the time needed doesn't mean anything about the outcome?

Comment: Correct. It only indicates (i) how much other work the editor has, (ii) her style of working, e.g. working in LIFO order, FIFO order, or in batches of related work that accumulates over a couple of weeks.

Comment: And is there any radical difference befween status "with editor" and "decision in process" (after second review)?

Comment: I have no idea. This may be specific to the online system a journal uses.